# Test run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, dagger-hilt, android-instrumentation

**Issue:** I am using Github Actions for CI and after pushing the code into Git CI workflow runs and showing me an error on FCMService file. Previously there were no error was showing on this file before implementing instrumentation testing.

I have implemented Instrumentation testing in android application (built in Kotlin and jetpack compose).
I am using DaggerHilt for dependenty Injection.

Here is my implemented code

//module build.gradle

```
android{
   defaultConfig {
      testInstrumentationRunner "org.xxx.xxx.CustomTestRunner"
   }
}
```

// CustomeTestRunner

```
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

//TestClass

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

@get:Rule
val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

@Before
fun init() {
    hiltRule.inject()
}

@Test
fun useAppContext() {
    println("Print message <- useAppContext <- ExampleInstrumentationTest")
    // Context of the app under test.
    /*val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
    assertEquals(26, appContext.applicationInfo.minSdkVersion)*/
  }
}
```

I have few more test case and good thing is each and every test case in local running successfully.

**Log Message In GitHub Action Workflow**

```
> Task :AndroidApp:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest
Starting 0 tests on test(AVD) - 9
Test run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.
Logcat of last crash: 
Process: org.xxx.xxx_android.dev, PID: 7827

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service org.xxx.xxx.FCMService: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have 
added the HiltAndroidRule.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3544)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:199)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1666)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The component was not created. Check that you have added the HiltAndroidRule.
at dagger.hilt.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:83)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.TestApplicationComponentManager.generatedComponent(TestApplicationComponentManager.java:96)
at dagger.hilt.android.testing.HiltTestApplication.generatedComponent(HiltTestApplication.java:50)
at dagger.hilt.EntryPoints.get(EntryPoints.java:59)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ServiceComponentManager.createComponent(ServiceComponentManager.java:70)
at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ServiceComponentManager.generatedComponent(ServiceComponentManager.java:58)
at org.xxxxx.xxxxx.Hilt_FCMService.generatedComponent(Hilt_FCMService.java:59)
at org.xxxxx.xxxxx.Hilt_FCMService.inject(Hilt_FCMService.java:53)
at org.xxxxx.xxxxx.Hilt_FCMService.onCreate(Hilt_FCMService.java:30)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3532)
```

This is how my FCMService is defined

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FCMService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    @Inject lateinit var preferenceService: PreferenceService
    // ......
}
```

I already gone through the documentations and looked for solutions but unable to fix this one. Please help me

Comment: I faced with the same issue after upgrading the gradle version to 8.1 and kotlin to 1.9.0, have you found any clue about it?

Comment: Yes, there was an issue with emulator version that I've used in Instrumentation testing. So, I updated emulator android version to latest one and it fixed this issue. But the funny thing is after resolving this issue I am getting another issue now, Only some times Github actions is unable to start it's inbuild emulator.